# May I redistribute Windows 10 IoT?

Tags: windows-iot, licensing

Say I have a Raspberry Pi 2, built something around it and wrote a piece of Windows 10 IoT software for it. Let's call the whole thing a "product" which fulfills a particular purpose.

**May I sell the product in this form or do I need a (commercial) Windows 10 IoT license?**

From other answers, I found that redistributing the hardware is not an issue. This question is about Windows 10 only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can distribute it. You can find the actual terms in the [Commercial Terms of Use](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/Commercialization.htm). The relevant part is section 1.a:

> a) **Grant.** Microsoft grants you non-exclusive, limited, worldwide license rights to distribute Embedded Systems containing a Runtime Image if you sublicense such image to an End User by means of License Terms.